# setState issue: The DOM gets updated but doesn't get reflected in the UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rendering, setstate

I have a Component, within the component there are two dropdown. On selecting value on the “name” dropdown, the “value” dropdown gets displayed.

For this purpose, I’m using setState. On selection, the state is updated, Component is rendered, I can see the changes in state with the console log inside the render().  It is getting reflected in the Browser that the DOM has appended another dropdown. But it is not visible in the UI.

I’m using setState since I want to update the store state only once the changes are finalised by clicking on “save” button. On clicking on “cancel”, the component state changes are reverted back to store state which I have stored in the variable “already_selected_details”.

But none of these changes are reflected in the UI (but they are reflected in the DOM).

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Dropdown from './Dropdown'
    import Modal from './Modal'
    import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom'

    let already_selected_details=[];

    class CarInfo extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                details: []
            };
        }
        componentWillMount() {
            this.state.details = this.props.details;
        }
        componentDidMount() {
            var nameElement = findDOMNode(this.refs.nameBox);
            $(nameElement).on('change',this.handleSelectChange.bind(this));
            var valueElement = findDOMNode(this.refs.valueBox);
            $(valueElement).on('change',this.handleSelectChange.bind(this));
        }
        handleClick(event) {
            this.props.actions.getDetails();
            this.props.actions.toggleDisplayModal();
            already_selected_details = this.state.details;
        }
        handleSelectChange(event) {
            let id = event.target.isd;
            let fn = id.split('_')[0];
            id = parseInt(id.split('_')[1]);

            if(fn == "name") {
                let value = event.target.value;
                this.setState({
                    details: this.state.details.map((detail, idx) => {
                        return idx==id ? Object.assign({}, detail, {name: value}) : detail;
                    })
                });
            }
            else if(fn =="value") {
                let value = [].filter.call(event.target.options, function (option) {
                    return option.selected;
                }).map(function (option) {
                    return option.value;
                });
                this.state.details[id].value = value;
                this.setState({
                    details: this.state.details
                })
            }
        }
        cancelSelection() {
            this.setState({
                details: already_selected_details
            }, () => {
                this.props.actions.toggleDisplayModal();
            })
        }
        updateSelection() {
            this.props.actions.setDetails(this.state.details);
            this.props.actions.toggleDisplayModal();
        }

        render() {

            return (
                <div className="row">
                <a className="clickable" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}><span>{this.props.details.length==1 && this.props.details[0].name=="" ? "ADD " : "EDIT "}</span><span>DETAILS</span></a>
                {
                    this.props.displayModal ?
                    <Modal>
                        <div className="modal">
                            <div className="modal-header">Select Details</div>
                            <div className="modal-body">{
                                this.state.details.map((detail, index) => {
                                    console.log(index, detail.name, detail.value);
                                    return (
                                        <div>
                                            <Dropdown class_name="col s12 m6 l3">
                                                <div className={"input-field col s12"}>
                                                    <select className={detail.name!="" ? "dropdown-select" : "dropdown-select initial"} ref="nameBox" id={"name_"+index} defaultValue={detail.name!="" ? detail.name : ""}>
                                                        <option value="" disabled>Select Name</option>
                                                        {
                                                            Object.keys(this.props.attributes.details).map((detail_name) => {
                                                                return <option value={detail_name} key={detail_name}>{detail_name}</option>
                                                            })
                                                        }
                                                    </select>
                                                    <label></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </Dropdown>
                                            {
                                                detail.name !== "" ?
                                                <Dropdown class_name="col s12 m6 l3">
                                                    <div className={"input-field col s12"}>
                                                        <select multiple className={detail.value==="" ? "dropdown-select initial" : "dropdown-select"} ref="valueBox" id={"value_"+index} defaultValue={detail.value==="" ? "" : detail.value}>
                                                            <option value="" disabled>Select Value</option>
                                                            {
                                                                detail.name !== "" ?
                                                                this.props.attributes.details[detail.name].map((detail_value) => {
                                                                    return <option value={detail_value} key={detail_value}>{detail_value}</option>
                                                                })
                                                                : null
                                                            }
                                                        </select>
                                                        <label></label>
                                                    </div>
                                                </Dropdown>
                                                : null
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }</div>
                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col s12 m5"><a className="btn" onClick={this.cancelSelection.bind(this)}>Cancel</a></div>
                                    <div className="col s12 m7"><a className="btn" onClick={this.updateSelection.bind(this)}>Save</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Modal>
                    : null
                }
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

    export default CarInfo
```

The Dropdown Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Dropdown extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.class_name}>{this.props.children}</div>
        )
    }
}

export default Dropdown
```

I have read a lot of problems in stack overflow and tried other ways to update the state but in vain.
Can you please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please provide us the Dropdown component and create a jsfiddle? You can fork this react jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/ and save your fiddle and share with us.

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo Sure, will create a jsfiddle. For the meanwhile I have added the Dropdown component.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is not a best practice with React: $(nameElement).on('change',this.handleSelectChange.bind(this));

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo I had to use this since I'm using materialize select. I doubt that this could be causing the problem. Still, I'll replace materialize select and see how it goes.

Comment: Ensure even that you're not updating the props.attributes.details reference and same thing for state. When you will have a jsFiddle it will be more simple to debug.

Comment: attributes state changes when the text is clicked to open the modal. this.props.actions.getDetails() action updates the store's attribute state. But otherwise it is not updated.